# Find a matrix so that $A^2$ not equal to 0 but $A^3$ is [Strang P78 2.4.23]

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> (a) Find a nonzero matrix $A$ for which $A^2 = 0$.
>   (b) Find a matrix that has $A^2 \neq 0$ but $A^3 = 0$.

**Solution for (a):** Let $A := \text{column $\times$ row} = \mathbf{cr^T} \neq \mathbf{0}$ where $\mathbf{c,r}$ are column vectors.
I'd like: $A^2 = \mathbf{c\color{green}{r^Tc}r^T} = \mathbf{0}. \mathbf{\color{green}{r^Tc = 0}}$ would imply this.
Thus, for want of a counterexample, choose $\mathbf{r} = (0,k)$ and $\mathbf{c} = (k,0)^T. \quad \blacksquare$

(b) Since I chose $\mathbf{c, r}$ such that  $\mathbf{\color{green}{r^Tc = 0}}$, thus $A^3 = \mathbf{c\color{green}{r^Tc}\color{green}{r^Tc}r^T} = 0.$

$\Large{1.}$  Could someone please reveal and expound on the intermediate steps and thoughts towards devising a (counterexample) for $A^3$? Please don't answer with just a counterexample.

$\Large{2.}$ How would one foreknow/previse to define $A := \text{column $\times$ row}$?

Comment: There are no solutions of the form $cr^T$. And what do you need Spurs, Anzatzes, square roots, involutes and questing for?

Comment: @LePressentiment : Did you use some software to translate this question into English?

Comment: I've pruned my OP. No software.

Comment: For part (a), just take a square matrix $A$ larger than 1-by-1 filled almost entirely with zeros and $A^2$ is probably $0$.

Comment: Check out Jordan normal form (if you have not learnt it yet), it decompose any general matrix into block where each is the sum of the shift matrix (as shown in the answer below, either that or shifting in the opposite direction) and a eigenvalue. Assume that you work in a algebra closed field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A* can be the matrix such that, multiplying any vector (*x, y, z*) by *A*, changes the vector by "pushing" every number in the vector down one position, and putting 0 at the top. That is, *A*(*x, y, z*)=(0, *x, y*).

So, multiplying any vector by *A*^2 will not always result in 0, but multiplying any vector by *A*^3 *will* always result in 0. This meets the requirements in the question.

To find the entries of this *A*, multiply *A* by each vector in the standard basis, and these results are the columns of *A*. So we get

\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}

Answer (score 5):

You want there to be a vector $v$ with $A^2\cdot v\neq0$ but $A^3\cdot v=0$. You can easily check that then $v,A\cdot v,A^2\cdot v$ must be a free (i.e., linearly independent) family: if there were a nontrivial linear dependence, take one with a minimal number of nonzero coefficients (at least two since the individual vectors cannot be zero); now apply $A$ sufficiently often to kill off the final nonzero coefficient, leaving exactly one less nonzero coefficient, which gives a contradiction.

For an easy example, take the (sub)space generated by $v,A\cdot v,A^2\cdot v$. The matrix of $A$ on this basis will be
$$
  A'=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
which provides your example.

My argument shows that you need $A$ to have rank at least$~2$ (as $A\cdot v$ and $A^2\cdot v$ are linearly independent elements of the image of $A$); hence taking for $A$ a product $cr^T$ of a $n\times 1$ and a $1\times n$ matrix will never work.

Comment: Thank you very much. $\Large{1.1}$ Is there a more rudimental synonym for "free family"; my intro Lin Alg textbook hasn't used it? $\Large{1.2}$ You wrote that "taking for $A$ a product ... will never work." Doesn't the solution show that $A := \mathbf{cr^T}$ does beget a counterexample, such as the one in my OP?  Also, could you please explain Q2 (now enumerated in my OP)?

Comment: Free family = linearly independent (ordered) set of vectors

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "beget a counterexample"; however (1) a (single column)$\times$(single row) product always has rank at most$~1$, so (2) if $A$ is such a matrix then for any vector $v$, the triplet of vectors $v$, $A\cdot v$ and $A^2\cdot v$ will be linearly dependent, hence (3) in such a situation either $A^2\cdot v=0$ or $A^3\cdot v\neq0$, and finally (4) if $A^3\cdot v=0$ for all $v$ then $A^2\cdot v=0$ for all $v$ as well, so $A$ is not an example of (b) in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much again. Upvoted. Since my textbook presents "rank" but far after this question, is it possible to answer without "rank"? In any respect, I'll return here later.

Comment: One can also contemplate over why you can never find a $2 \times 2$ matrix that works for case 2. Here one can apply minimal polynomials for example.

Answer (score 4):

You find yourself in a house with 3 rooms and no doors.

If you fall asleep in the first room, you disappear.

If you fall asleep in the second room, you have a 50% chance of waking up in the first room, otherwise you disappear.

If you fall asleep in the third room, you have a 33% chance of waking up in the first room, 33% chance of waking up in the second room, otherwise you disappear.

On arrival you could be in any room.  On the first morning you can only wake up in the first or second room.  On the second morning you can only wake up in the first room.  On the third morning there is nowhere you can be.

You describe your situation with a transition matrix.

$$ M = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \frac 12 & 0 & 0 \\ \frac 13 & \frac 13 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
$$ M^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \frac 16 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
$$ M^3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$