# Let $A$ be a matrix. If $A^{n-1} \neq \bf{0}$ but $A^{n} = \bf{0}$, what does it say about the matrix $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

> [image: Full question]

Since the question doesn't say *find all matrices* $A$, I will only produce one example for both:

a. $A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

b. $A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 &0\\1&0 & 0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$ from [Find a matrix so that $A^2$ not equal to 0 but $A^3$ is [Strang P78 2.4.23]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506922/find-a-matrix-so-that-a2-not-equal-to-0-but-a3-is-strang-p78-2-4-23)

Just based off of these two, I would conjecture that

- Matrices $A$ satisfying $A^{n-1} \neq \bf{0}$ but $A^{n} = 0$ must be such that they are of dimension $n$

However, there is a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ that satisfies $A\neq \bf{0}$ but $A^2= \bf{0}$, namely

$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

The next thing I could think of was:

- Matrices $A$ satisfying $A^{n-1} \neq \bf{0}$ but $A^{n} = 0$ must be such that they have a dimension of *at least* $n$

But I don't know if that's it or not...

---

Question(s):

1. What was I meant to conjecture?

Comment: The question is about *a* conjecture, it does not specify which one. You have done one, so it is a logically correct answer. If you just answer *Yes, I can make a conjecture* without even mentioning which one, it would be logically correct as well. If the teacher wants you to do more, it must be specified in the question explicitly.

Comment: @A.Γ., I technically have done what the question has asked but I feel like the author must have put this question in because there's **something to be concluded here**. I guess I'm asking for what would be a conjecture that is both correct and logically follows from the two examples.

Comment: Your conjecture is a very good one. The number $n$ is known as the *nilpotency index*, and it is less than or equal to the size of the matrix.

Comment: @A.Γ., that's fascinating stuff. I'm inclined to accept that if you want to put it as an answer (if no one else answers).

Comment: I think the question *does* mean to find *all* matrices that satisfy the requirements. It doesn't say "Find a matrix...", "Find some matrices" or specify the number of matrices you need to find. So, "Find matrices $A$" should be interpreted as "Find all matrices $A$".

Comment: @user1551, that could be a bit hard (for me) as all I'm exposed to so far [in Chapter 1 of Multivariable Mathematics (https://www.amazon.com/Multivariable-Mathematics-Algebra-Calculus-Manifolds/dp/047152638X ) ] are the very fundamentals such as matrices are linear transformations, how to transpose matrices, inverse of 2x2 matrix, how to multiply matrices etc. At this point in the book, I'm not supposed to know anything about eigenvalues, row space, or even Gaussian elimination... However, I would be grateful if you could provide a proof of all matrices that satisfy both conditions!

Comment: @user1551 I think you're misreading the question there. If they want *all*, they'll say *all*. The only reason it's pluralised is because an example is sought for each of two problems.

Comment: @user1551: As the author in question, I'll say you're misinterpreting, as well. If I'd meant "all," I surely would have said "all." It certainly wouldn't be appropriate at this juncture in that course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author concurs with your conjecture. He was hoping that you'd realize that a matrix with $A^n=O$ but $A^{n-1}\ne O$ must be of size *at least* $n\times n$. And of course you were expected to find examples, not find *all*. (Perhaps for $2\times 2$ matrices you should try to find all?)

What you might also notice is that you can have any number of $1$'s on the sub- (or super-)diagonal ... in order to get specific examples. You have $3\times 3$ examples with one $1$ and with two $1$'s.

But you would get credit for a correct answer in the author's view. :)

Comment: Hi @TedShifrin!!! Thanks so much for weighing in! I've indeed done so for the 2x2 case here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3409265/find-all-matrices-a-in-mathbbr2-times2-such-that-a2-bf0/3409364#3409364)

Comment: Yes, and of course when you post a question on MSE, people will answer using all sorts of machinery you don't know yet, unless you make your context *very* specific. You approached that question as I had intended.

Answer (score 2):

We can generalize your answers to (a), (b) by saying an $n\times n$ matrix $A_{ij}=\delta_{i,\,j-1}$ satisfies $A^n=O\ne A^{n-1}$. Indeed, defining a basis $(e_i)_j=\delta_{ij}$, $(Ae_i)_j=A_{jk}\delta_{ik}=A_{ji}=(e_{i-1})_j$, so repeatedly applying $A$ to the basis elements moves backwards through it until we turn $e_1$ into the zero vector.

But you've also conjectured no smaller matrices satisfy $A^n=O=A^{n-1}$. One way to see this is to note that a $k\times k$ choice of $A$ with $k<n$ has a degree-$k$ characteristic polynomial that would, if $A^n=O$, need to divide $\lambda^n$ by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, so it must be of the form $\lambda^k$. But then $A^k=O$ by said theorem, whence $A^{n-1}=O$, a contradiction.